# Is this the only possibility for $F(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

We're given that $\int_{0}^{a}{f\left( x \right)dx=a}$ and $f(x)$ is continuous, then:

$$\int_{0}^{a}{f\left( x \right)dx=a}=F\left( a \right)-F\left( 0 \right)$$
$$F\left( a \right)-F\left( 0 \right)=a$$
$$F\left( x \right)-c=x$$
$$∴\int_{}^{}{f\left( x \right)dx}=F\left( x \right)=x+c$$

Is this the only possible function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you told that $\int_{0}^{a}{f\left( x \right)dx=a}$ for *all* values of $a$? or just for some fixed value of $a$?

If you are told it is true for all values of $a$, then your derivation is correct. If you only know it for some fixed value of $a$, then the step where you replaced $a$ with $x$ is not justified.

Comment: yeh for all values of $a$, thanks